# Issue with PUT Request in Nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, web, get, put

I have below code which is working fine for GET and POST but not for PUT in node js. I am using method overloading for GET and PUT. Below is my app.js code.

Can you please help me if I am missing something here. Basically I am trying to do a PUT request by providing customer name in URL and other details in the BODY section of the request. So if the customer with name exists, it will update it otherwise create it newly.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const AuthRoutes = Router();
const AppRoutes = Router();
AuthRoutes.get('/customer/:customername', getCustomerbyname);
AuthRoutes.post('/calculate/:id', calculate);
AuthRoutes.put('/customer/:customername', saveCustomer);
```

Below URL I am trying for PUT.

> https://domainname/customer/abc

I don't know what I am missing here.

> Error - You don't have permission to access /domainname/customer/abc

Comment: Your error sounds like a permission issue, not a routing issue.  What code do you have that is enforcing authentication?  Also, how is the PUT being sent?  From what type of client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// routes.js
import { Router } from 'express';
const Router = Router()

Router.get('/customer/:customername', getCustomerbyname)
      .put('/customer/:customername', saveCustomer);

Router.post('/calculate/:id', calculate);


module.exports = router





/// in app.js or server.js or index.js 

// import the router 
import {router as customerRoutes} from './routes.js

// add to your app 
app.use('/',customerRoutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have put an Authentication for the route but have forgotten to authenticate for the same? `Middleware` might have been set up ,so perhaps try authenticating.